# Is it possible to combine system link and split screen play on Halo 3's campaign?

Tags: halo-3, xbox-system-link

I know that online you can play 4 player campaign, but on split screen mode you are limited to two players. Is it pssible to play both System Link and split screen with two consoles, and two players each?

<sup>(Between free games with my 360's replacement, the free game when someone got it as a present, and the disc in ODST and the fact that Gamestop only give €3 for trade ins I do have several Halo 3 game discs)</sup>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Halo is one of the few games that allows you do both split screen and live/system link at the same time. It is possible to play four player campaign with two per xbox over system link.

Comment: As good as 4-player campaign play is, nothing beats a 4v4 with two TVs, with each team having their own screen. Just saying. :)